# List only categories i specify

Tags: categories

Ok, so this site's navigation is built up from Categories.

However, my client wants specific grouping of the navigation items, ie.

```
x
y
z
----
1
2
----
3
4
----
6
```

There is no conceivable way to group these logically. So i think my best bet is to just do something like `echo WpCat('x')` and `echo WpCat('4')` i know this isnt the code but the general idea is how can i only echo certain category names as and when i need to?

Thanks

Comment: What if you use the built in menu option? I let you choose which elements you wanna insert (pages, categories, custom post types, custom...) right in the WP administration.

Comment: Sorry i was a little skant with information. I have a main nav with about, contact, etc, but this is a categories menu, with just categories.

Comment: This menu option lets you create as many menus as you want. It's just a matter of where you call them after.

Answer (score 2):

@Kevin is right. You can create any number of menus in

> Appearance -> Menus

Just create a new menu for your categories. Lets call it **categories**. You can call this menu in your theme using this code.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'categories' )); ?>
```